# Getting all Twitter Follows (ids) with Groovy?

Tags: api, twitter, groovy

I was reading an article [here](http://kousenit.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/twitter-follower-value-revisited/) and it looks like he is grabbing the IDs by the 100s. I thought it was possible to grab by 5000 each time?

The reason I'm asking is because sometimes there are profiles with much larger amounts of followers and you wouldn't have enough actions to do it all in one hour if one was to grab it by 100 each time.

So is it possible to grab 5000 ids each time, if so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET statuses/followers as shown in that article [has been deprecated](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/followers), but did used to return batches of 100

If you're trying to get follower ids, you would use [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids). This does return batches of up to 5000, and should just require you to change the URL slightly (see example URL at the bottom of the documentation page)

Comment: Would using this new URL require OAuth? I gave it a quick go and I'm getting an unauthorized error

Comment: I pasted the URL into a browser and got json back. I'll check when I am at a computer in the morning...

Comment: You are correct, I'm unsure of what I did wrong the first time but it worked fine the second time. Changing json to xml however returns blank :/

Comment: @StartingGroovy odd...  https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi works for me...